# sql query for 2 tables to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables. I want to write update query

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feasibility](
[FeasibilityID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[orderstatus] [varchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Feasibility_orderstatus]  DEFAULT ('Not Placed')
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Feasibility] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
     (
[FeasibilityID] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
     ) ON [PRIMARY]



     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderMaster](
[orderid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[feasibilityid] [int] NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_OrderMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
[orderid] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to update the orderstatus in feasibility table to 'Closed' of all those records that are present in ordermaster table

Comment: What've u tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this...

```
  update feasibility set orderstatus='Closed' where feasiablityID in(select distinct          
  feasiablityID from ordermaster)
```

you should you Distinct keyword to efficient, fast and error less working..........

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have `JOIN` statement rather than `IN`. It will be much faster. 
You can try this below

```
UPDATE F
SET    F.OrderStatus = 'closed'
FROM   Feasibility  AS F
JOIN   OrderMaster AS O
ON     F.FeasibilityID = O.FeasibilityID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
update Feasibility set orderstatus='closed' where 
FeasibilityID in (select feasibilityid from OrderMaster)
```

Answer (score -1):

try out this

```
update Feasibility set orderstatus='closed' where FeasibilityID in (select FeasibilityID from OrderMaster)
```